# Difference between "conda install" with "-c anaconda" and without it

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am new to python and I am trying to install new packages in Anaconda. I am using anaconda prompt and Windows 10.

1. Can you please explain what is the difference between `conda install` with `-c anaconda` and without it? For example `conda install -c anaconda mysqlclient` and `conda install mysqlclient`.
2. Which is better to use when and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the -c option, you are specifying the channel from which to get the package. The default is -c anaconda, so they are similar. To use packages built locally, you would use -c local.
Here is a link for more info:
[Docs explaining usage of conda install](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html)

Comment: What exactly means "channel"? Can you please explain that to person who is new to python and anaconda?

Comment: Think of it as the repo from which the libraries will be pulled from, kinda like node registry js, pypi for python or maven central for java

Comment: So version without `-c anaconda` first is looking at anaconda repo and after is also looking in other repos? So version with `-c anaconda` forces only to look in anaconda repo?

Comment: Starts there, to force it to not use other channels, you need the --override-channels switch together with the -c option

Comment: Am I understand it correctly that it is recommended to use with `-c anaconda`?

Comment: Unless you have a reason not to, yeah you should

Answer (score 9):

`conda`, as you know is a package manager that can install packages to your machine. If you do `conda install`, it needs a place to search for these packages to download them from. For `conda`, this is solved with the concept of `channels`, which are, as @David Kabii has pointed out, like repositories that can exist either locally/a network location or be a url. By default, `conda install` will try to download packages from `repo.anaconda.com`, specifically on windows, these locations are searched by default:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

More information on the difference can be found in the docs on [using default repositories](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-repositories/).

Now if you go to www.anaconda.org and search for a package, let's say `numpy`, you will see that it is available from different channels. You should only worry about those in case a package is not available from the default channels. This you can also check by running `conda search <package name>` which will list all available versions in the currently configured channels.

Coming to your question. The `-c` options specifies an additional channel to search first which is needed if a package is not available from default channels. E.g. some bioinformatics tools are only available by specifying `-c bioconda`. For those packages that are available from the default channels you should not specify anything and using `-c anaconda` will make no difference, as the `anaconda` channel is only a mirror of the default ones and should not be used (see the [channel description](https://anaconda.org/anaconda)):

> This channel is used internally for mirroring. You should very much prefer https://repo.anaconda.com, which is conda's default and needs no "-c" setting.